# Pointer and Character

Tags: c, string, pointers, character

My code is suposed to get the separated numbers, the thing is I have already seen numerous tutorials and I do not understand why it runs when I set:

```
p = "123 23 32"
out>>
123
23
32
0
0
```

But when I set it equals to character array It only finds the first number, event though I "walk" in to the `p` pointer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int N, i=0, NUMERO = 1, FINAL = 0;
    char ORDEM[100000], *p = ORDEM;

    scanf("%s", ORDEM);
    p = ORDEM;

    for(i = 0; i<5; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", atoi(p));
        while (*p != ' ') p++;
        if (*p == ' ') p++;
        if (*p == '\0') break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%s", ORDEM);
```

`scanf()` delimits by space characters. Thus `ORDEM` contains only `"123"` in your test case.

To read the whole line, you should call `fgets()`.

```
fgets(ORDEM, 100000, stdin);
```

Comment: Man, I have so much shame, I have really try hard to make this work, and the solution is so simple. I did not know scanf() only read delimited by space characters, sorry!